# What data structure can be used to store firewall rules?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, firewall

Given a list of allowed firewall rules, where each rule is of the form

`protocol, port-range, ip-range`

what is the best data structure to store these rules so that I can efficiently decide whether to allow a packet to pass through or not. For the packet, I have `protocol, port, ip`.

In other words, how are firewalls implemented. How are security groups implemented in AWS?

Note: If this is the wrong forum for such questions, where can I ask this question?

Answer (score 2):

The actual data structure would be very simple, just an array of objects where each object represents a rule and has the three fields `protocol, port-range, ip-range` - and I would have thought, the type of rule (deny, allow etc). When you intercept a request, you'd get its protocol etc, and then iterate the list to see which rules are matched. Pretty basic in outline. However the question 'How are firewalls implemented?' (in detail) is of course a much bigger question involving in-depth understanding of networking. The question "How are security groups implemented in AWS?" is even more unanswerable - and a completely separate matter.

Comment: When you have a lot of rules and a lot of traffic, iterating a list for each packet is not the way to go. You'd want a decision tree of some sort that provides much better performance than iterating a list.